# multiple threads call wait(), then notify(), result is deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, notify

I want to know how I can solve the following problem:
I have created multiple threads of the same kind. They are all have a run-method with a timed while-loop and a synchronized-block, in which wait() is called first, then notify(). This results in all threads staying in wait()-state and none of them calling notify().
How can I overcome this deadlock-situation? Is there a solution using wait()/notify()?

```
public class Deadlock3 implements Runnable {
    LinkedList<Integer> intList;
    public Deadlock3(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
        intList = list;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }
    public void run() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 10) {
                synchronized (intList) {
                    Integer number = intList.removeFirst();
                    System.out.println(number + " removed");
                    number = (number + 3) % 21;
                    intList.addLast(number);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+number + " added");
                    intList.wait();
                    intList.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        for (Integer i : list) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            new Deadlock3(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answers...

Comment: I don't understand. Why did you write this code knowing that the `wait` will block forever since nothing exists to `notify` it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: you're misunderstanding how to use wait and notify, throw this code away and read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: The task is to find the reason and the solution of the deadlock-situation. I do understand why the threads are stuck in wait()-position ,but I do not know how to solve it.
Can I call notify()/notifyAll() "externally" to keep the threads running?

Comment: @drwood187 Yes, if one thread calls `wait`, another thread needs to call `notify[All]`.

Comment: this looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32546029/217324

Comment: The reason is, a call to `intList.wait()` will not return until some other thread calls `intList.notify()`.  All of your threads do the wait() call before any of them can do the notify() call.  If they're all waiting, then who's going to wake them up?

Comment: The solution is not something anybody can help you with until you say what the program is supposed to _do_.

Comment: This is not a deadlock. There is no circular chain of locks. It is just a blocked application due to incorrect design.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I overcome this deadlock-situation? Is there a solution using wait()/notify()?

Let's take a look at your code.  You start 4 threads by calling `new Thread(this).start();` in the constructor of `Deadlock3`.  That's a really bad pattern by the way because the thread can start using the fields *before* the object has been fully constructed.  It is better to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   new Thread(new Deadlock3(list)).start();
}
```

But that's not the problem.  When the `Deadlock3` starts, the first thread synchronizes on `intList`, does some counting and stuff, and calls `intList.wait()`.  This waits until someone calls `intList.notify()` or `notifyAll()`.  The first thread goes to sleep waiting and releases the `intList` lock.  The problem is that each thread goes through the same process.  They all are waiting on `intList` and no one reaches the `notifyAll()`.

The real question is what is the point of calling `wait()` and notify?  As I see it you don't need them and they can be removed.  If you need them, please explain why?

When I remove those lines and run the program finishes after spitting out a bunch of the following cycles:

```
...
18 removed
Thread-3 - 0 added
19 removed
Thread-3 - 1 added
20 removed
Thread-3 - 2 added
0 removed
Thread-3 - 3 added
1 removed
Thread-3 - 4 added
2 removed
...
```

Hope this helps.